# Cannot access key from an API in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm pretty new on Nuxt JS.
I fillow tutorials on nuxt js, and I can't show a {{planet.title}} on my page.
But if I use {{$data}} i see all the planets.
I want the title of the planet's name I have in the slug (here it's earth but it can be jupiter or mars)

`_slug.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <NuxtLogo />
      <h1 class="title">planet.title here => {{ planet.title }}</h1>
      <pre> $data here => {{ $data }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NuxtLogo from "~/components/NuxtLogo";
export default {
  components: {NuxtLogo},
  async asyncData() {
    const planet = await fetch(
      'https://api.nuxtjs.dev/planets'
    ).then((res) => res.json())
    return { planet }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

My Web Page :

[image: webpage]

Comment: You don't really need to import the component in Nuxt as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components Also, try to not mix and match `async/await` and `.then()`. Keep using `async/await`.

Comment: You can check my answer with the 2nd snippet of code. It is essentially showing how to fetch a specific ID from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can improve your code

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <NuxtLogo />
      <h1 class="title">planet.title here => {{ planet.title }}</h1>
      <pre> $data here => {{ $data }}</pre>
      <section>
        <div v-for="planet in planets" :key="planet.slug">
            <p>Title of my planet: {{ planet.title }}</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData() {
    const call = await fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/planets')
    const planets = await call.json()
    return { planets }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

PS: don't forget the `:key`.

---

The API returns an array. If you want to access the `title` of the first planet, use `planet[0].title`.

You can also of course loop on the whole array with `v-for`. More info here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Comment: I want to show the title of the planet'name I have in the slug

Comment: @NolanRassant you need to have a specific API endpoint for this. Here you have an endpoint fetching all the planets. You need to have one for a specific one.

Comment: I don't understand, I followed this tutorial : https://explorers.netlify.com/learn/get-started-with-nuxt/nuxt-dynamic-routes . She can show the planets title and I can't

Comment: The actual link is giving you the exact code needed to have it work. Follow the video til the end. Or check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663907/cannot-access-key-from-an-api-in-nuxt/69664096?noredirect=1#comment123136609_69663907).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Planet is an array so you need to iterate over the array and then print the values that you want for that array try with

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in planets">
    {{ item.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`planet` as you can see when you display the variable `$data` is an a array of planets.

You should rename `planet` variable to `planets` so it represents better its contents.

To display a planet, you need to get a it from the `planets` array:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <NuxtLogo />
      <h1 class="title">earth.title here => {{ earth.title }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NuxtLogo from "~/components/NuxtLogo";
export default {
  components: {NuxtLogo},
  async asyncData() {
    const planets = await fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/planets')
        .then((res) => res.json())

    const earth = planets[0];

    return { planets, earth }
  }
}
</script>
```